# Xamarin XAML NavigationPage with ContentPage and IconImageSource

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm struggling from 2 days with this situation in Xamarin Xaml and i can't find any help from MS documentation and here on stackoverflow maybe I can't define this problem in the right way, here is my issue:
I can't figure out how I can set the ContentPage inside the NavigationPage if I have another tag defined inside.

In a standard TabbedTage i define my pages in this way:

```
<NavigationPage Title="Print Label" IconImageSource="{StaticResource Key=icon}">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:PrintLabelsPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

If I want to set a custom IconImageSource to use FontAwesome glyphs instead of bitmap image i use this techinque successfully:

```
<NavigationPage Title="Print Label">
    <NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource 
                FontFamily="FARegular" 
                Size="Large"
                Glyph="{x:Static fa:Glyphs.ShoppingCart }" />
    </NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
</NavigationPage>
```

But if I want both the feature i can't do it in any way:

```
<NavigationPage Title="Print Label">
    <NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource 
                FontFamily="FARegular" 
                Size="Large"
                Glyph="{x:Static fa:Glyphs.ShoppingCart }" />
    </NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:PrintLabelsPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

I have published a repo on github
https://github.com/mmassari/TestTabbedPageWithIcons

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: what happens whey you try to do both?  Is there an error or exception?

Comment: What happens if you put `IconImageSource` into `PrintLabelsPage`'s XAML? I have no idea whether the NavigationPage can get it from there; just brainstorming how this could be done differently.

Comment: If I try to put both tags inside NavigationPage i got compilation error.
And the icon to be displayed inside the Tab have to be setted inside the TabbedPage

Comment: `i got compilation error`  Could you please post the error log here? Besides, could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have posted a repo on github [link](https://github.com/mmassari/TestTabbedPageWithIcons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the tip mentioned `x:Argument cannot follow any other elements or cotent. Move the x:Arguments elements to be the first`, you can just move the `x:Arguments` elements to be the first,just as follows:

```
<NavigationPage Title="TestSchedule" >
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:Page2 />
    </x:Arguments>
    <NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource FontFamily="FARegular" Size="Large" Glyph="&#xf164;" />
    </NavigationPage.IconImageSource>

</NavigationPage>
```

Not:

```
    <NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource FontFamily="FARegular" Size="Large" Glyph="&#xf164;" />
    </NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:Page2 />
    </x:Arguments>

</NavigationPage>
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe i did not try to move x:arguments on top... Shame on me! Thanks